# Check if a file contains strings and create an array for new strings

Tags: java, arrays, file

I need to create a method that will read the file, and check each word in the file. Each new word in the file should be stored in a string array. The method should be case insensitive. Please help.

The file says the following:
Ask not what your country can do for you
ask what you can do for your country

So the array should only contain: ask, not, what, your, country, can, do, for, you

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class TextAnalysis {

public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException {
    File in01 = new File("a5_testfiles/in01.txt");
    Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(in01);

    System.out.println("TEXT FILE STATISTICS");
    System.out.println("--------------------");
    System.out.println("Length of the longest word: " + longestWord(fileScanner));
    System.out.println("Number of words in file wordlist: " );
    countWords();
    System.out.println("Word-frequency statistics");

}

public static String longestWord (Scanner s) {
    String longest = "";
    while (s.hasNext()) {
        String word = s.next();
        if (word.length() > longest.length()) {
            longest = word;
        }
    }

    return (longest.length() + " " + "(\"" + longest + "\")");
}

public static void countWords () throws IOException {
    File in01 = new File("a5_testfiles/in01.txt");
    Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(in01);  
    int count = 0;

        while(fileScanner.hasNext()) {
            String word = fileScanner.next();
                count++;
        }

    System.out.println("Number of words in file: " + count);
}

public static int wordList (int words) {
    File in01 = new File("a5_testfiles/in01.txt");
    Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(in01); 

    int size = words;
    String [] list = new String[size];

    for (int i = 0; i <= size; i++) {

        while(fileScanner.hasNext()){
            if(!list[].contains(fileScanner.next())){
                list[i] = fileScanner.next();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: This code won't compile. Multiple errors. Are you stuck trying to compile this, or is there a question beyond that (once it successfully compiles)?

Answer (score 0):

You could always just try:

```
List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();

//read lines in your file all at once
List<String> allLines = Files.readAllLines(yourFile, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

for(int i = 0; i < allLines.size(); i++) {

    //change each line from your file to an array of words using "split(" ")".
    //Then add all those words to the list "words"
    words.addAll(Arrays.asList(allLines.get(i).split(" ")));

}

//convert the list of words to an array.
String[] arr = words.toArray(new String[words.size()]);
```

Using `Files.readAllLines(yourFile, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));` to read all the lines of `yourFile` is much cleaner than reading each individually. The problem with your approach is that you're counting the number of lines, not the number of words. If there are multiple words on one line, your output will be incorrect.

Alternatively, if you do not use Java 7, you can create a list of lines as follows and then count the words at the end (as opposed to your approach in `countWords()`:

```
List<String> allLines = new ArrayList<String>();

Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(yourFile);
while (fileScanner.hasNextLine()) {
     allLines.add(scanner.nextLine());    
}

fileScanner.close();
```

Then split each line as shown in the previous code and create your array. Also note that you should use a `try{} catch` block around your scanner rather than `throws` ideally.

Comment: Files is only available on Java 7+, however.  No telling if the OP has access to it.

Comment: Hi, I tried the second one, and it gave me an error: 
TextAnalysis.java:71: java.util.List is abstract; cannot be instantiated
  List<String>allLines = new List<String>();
                         ^

Comment: Try `List<String>allLines = new ArrayList<String>();`

Comment: Sorry, yes Mohammad is right - use an `ArrayList` or `LinkedList` in place of `List`.

Answer (score 0):

You could take advantage of my following code snippet (it will not store the duplicate words)!

```
File file = new File("names.txt");

FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
char[] c = new char[256];
while(fr.read(c) > 0){
    sb.append(c);
}


String[] ss = sb.toString().toLowerCase().trim().split(" ");
TreeSet<String> ts = new TreeSet<String>();

for(String s : ss)
    ts.add(s);

for(String s : ts){
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

---

And the output is:

```
ask
can
country
do
for
not
what
you
your
```

Comment: This is part of an assignment for a beginner programmer's course. And I have to use arrays to store the words. Later I'll have to write another method accessing these words by indicating the indexes of the array. I'm not sure if i'll be able to these with these code. But overall that IS what I want the code to do, but using arrays. And I need the Scanner to scan the file.

Comment: when you say a 'beginner programmer's course' does that mean you cannot use `FileReader` and `StringBuilder` either?

Comment: we haven't covered these yet, unfortunately